# Is there an easy way I can display a short message with the default Quick Look preview?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicklook

DRM-protected iTunes movie and music files show a fairly standard-looking Quick Look preview, but with an extra line of text added above the default material:

[image]

I'd like to be able to replicate this behavior for my DRM-protected custom document type, but so far I haven't found a way.  Is there an easy way to achieve this and still keep the system-default content and layout?  Sure, I could easily obtain all of the metadata and build my own preview, but then I'd have to worry about localizations and future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way is to build a custom Quick Look preview extension and/or plugin.

Comment: So is this what Apple does to achieve this behavior?

Comment: It uses a private framework to build a custom view instead of the public extension API because it predates it. Note that custom views are only supported for searchable items (file a bug if you want it for files as well). But to achieve a static preview for files, you can build a view, snapshot it to PDF, and return the PDF using the generator plugin API.